# SWIFT: Subscript int in String (Cnndition works, assignment not)

Tags: string, swift, int, subscript

I want to assign the first char of a string. Of course there is a advance function, but to me (I come from C++) it is much easier to read when simply using [index]. So I defined an extension for String type:

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[advance(self.startIndex, i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }

    ...
```

This works fine for a condition like:

```
if (s[0] == "u")
```

but when assigning this value like

```
var c = s[0]
```

I get an error that compiler can't subscript String with type of int.
But where is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the compiler cannot infer the return type of `subscript`, since these two `subscript` have the same input signature.

So you have to specify which `subscript` you want to use. Like this,

```
var c:Character = s[0]
```

or

```
var c:String = s[0]
```

Comment: YES! You are right. Now it's clear. The comparison adds the type needed from the constant string. Thank you very much!